# Why does second load of this dart:js date picker code error?

Tags: datepicker, dart

I use the following code in dart (chrome app):

```
js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.datepicker']).callMethod('datepicker', [new js.JsObject.jsify({'format':'yyyy-mm-dd'})]);
```

which works fine the first time this code is rendered. However, if I navigate away and back to the page, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Uncaught Error: NullError: Cannot call "split" on null
Stack Trace:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.DPGlobal.parseDate (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js:393:20)
    at Datepicker.update (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js:161:25)
    at new Datepicker (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js:84:8)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js:341:38)
    at Function.n.extend.each (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:2882)
    at n.fn.n.each (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:847)
    at $.fn.datepicker (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js:336:15)
    at JsObject.callMethod$2 (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/b2015.dart.js:19892:42)
    at navAccTranS24_closure.call$1 (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/b2015.dart.js:23116:58)
    at _RootZone.runUnary$2 (chrome-extension://lgndonjnifhllkkomohiinkfdaphgalc/b2015.dart.js:10124:18)
```

By navigate I mean I use `children.clear()` on the holding div the re-populate it with new html.

I presume I should only run this code once, or 'unload' it when I navigate away but I am just guessing here and would appreciate a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to do this new js.JsObject.jsify({'format':'yyyy-mm-dd'}), you should be able to just pass it in as a normal dart element {'format':'yyyy-mm-dd'}?

Comment: I suspect it's a timing issue. Maybe the jQuery element is not yet ready.  You could try to wrap your call with `new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds:200, ()  => js. context...);` if this helps we can try to fond a better strategy to align these actions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I did it with a delay of 1 second and still the same result.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas. Can you publish a minimal example which allows to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer https://gist.github.com/sierrakilo/1f4ce41b8a032d10f5d7

Comment: Sorry, but this is too incomplete. It doesn't even show which script tags you are using and where they are placed. It makes only sense to take a closer look when you can provide a minimal but complete runnable example where you have verified that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Well, thanks, but it's a simple question and I don't see why you need to see the whole app to say whether you know the answer or not.

Comment: Okay I didn't find a solution to this so I can't answer but by swapping from bootstrap date picker to jQuery ui date picker I got it working. HTH.